# Targeting all subclassed CCSprites (cocos2d)

Tags: methods, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm working on a method to end the level, but to do so, I have to see that all of the enemy character have been killed. 
If my enemies are CCSprites, how do I make a method that detects if all of them are dead? I'm tracking their health with an int called enemyHp. For example, this is an if statement I made to remove the enemy `if (enemy.enemyHp <= 0) {`

To recap - I want to make a method that detects when all enemies have been killed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add those sprites to an array (NSArray) and then loop through that array.

```
for(Enemy * enemy in enemies)
{
  if (enemy.enemyHp <= 0) {    
    //kill it
  }  
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what that first line is. Enemy is the array right? So what is enemies?

Comment: So just to make sure, would this method be effective?

Comment: -(void)allEnemiesKilled:(id)sender {
 for (NormalEnemy *tempEnemy in enemyArray) {
  if (enemy.enemyHp <= 0) {
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[LevelIntro node]]];
  }
 }
}